# regex match first and last word or any word

Tags: python, regex, file, file-io

I have a huge file with a list of data such as this:

```
 #fabulous       7.526   2301    2
 #excellent      7.247   2612    3
 #superb 7.199   1660    2
 #perfection     7.099   3004    4
 #terrific       6.922   629     1
```

I have a file containing a list of sentences like this:

```
Terrific Theo Walcott is still shit, watch Rafa and Johnny deal with him on Saturday.
its not that I'm a GSP fan, fabulous
Iranian general says Israel's Iron Dome can't deal with their missiles 
with J Davlar 11th. Main rivals are team Poland.
```

I want to check with regex the following:

1. if first word in every sentence matches any words in the file
   Example, if Terrific, its, Iranian, with occur in the file or not
2. if last word in sentence matches any words in the file
   Example, if saturday, fabulous, missiles , Poland occur in the file or not
3. if the 2 or 3 characters prefix and suffix of individual words in sentences matches 2 or 3 characters prefix and suffix in file
   example if Ter, its, Ira, wi matches to any 2 or 3 prefix of words in the file or not. Same applies to suffix.

I am so new to regex that I could think of this way but not getting the result:
term2.lower() is the first column in the file

```
    wordanalysis["trail"] = found if re.match(sentence[-1],term2.lower()) else not(found)
    wordanalysis["lead"] = found  if re.match(sentence[0],term2.lower()) else not(found)
```

Comment: I want to check if first word matches the list of words in the files. Why whats wrong with that? I m working on a project.

Comment: @r3mus aah sorry about that. and yes you got it right. check my edit for examples.

Comment: Updated answer, it works (tested) now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update:** Per awesome suggestion by @justhalf, no need to use regex for splitting the words. Remove the `.lower()` if you want a case sensitive match.

This will match the first word and last words (excluding any punctuation or trailing whitespace) in your list of data:

`(^\s?\w+\b|(\b\w+)[\.?!\s]*$)`

**Matches:**

```
MATCH 1-1. Terrific
MATCH 2-1. Saturday.
        2. Saturday
MATCH 3-1. its
MATCH 4-1. fabulous
        2. fabulous
MATCH 5-1. Iranian
MATCH 6-1. missiles 
        2. missiles
MATCH 7-1. with
MATCH 8-1. Poland. 
        2. Poland
```

**Implementation:**

```
import re, string

sentences = open("sentences.txt").read().splitlines()
data = open("data.txt").read()
pattern = re.compile(r"(^\s?\w+\b|(\b\w+)[\.?!\s]*$)")
for line in sentences:
    words = line.strip().split()
    first = words[0].lower()
    last = words[-1].translate(None, string.punctuation).lower()
    if (re.search(first, data, re.I)):
        print "Found " + first + " in data.txt"
    if (re.search(last, data, re.I)):
        print "Found " + last + " in data.txt"
```

This probably isn't the most elegant way of doing it, but you get the idea.

Code is tested and works, output is:

```
Found Terrific in data.txt
Found fabulous in data.txt
```

**Also** this doesn't accomplish your 3rd criteria, test this out and see if it's working so far for you.

Comment: Why do you need a regex to get the first and last word? You can just split based on whitespaces, like so: `words = line.strip().split(); first,last = words[0], words[-1]`

Comment: @justhalf good point, updated, and accommodating punctuation now.

Comment: how do I get the 2nd column of the data.txt?

Comment: what does re.I do? and what about keyword 'last', what does that line say?

Comment: re.I is a case insensitive match; first is the first word of the sentence, last is the last word