# Find Last Word in a String within a List (Pandas, Python 3)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a DF named 'Stories" that looks like this:

```
Story
The Man
The Man Child
The Boy of Egypt
The Legend of Zelda
```

Is there a way to extract the last word in each of those strings?

Something like:

```
Stories['Prefix'] = final['Story'].str.extract(r'([^ ]*)')
```

finds the prefix but I am not sure how to adapt it accordingly

I was hoping to end up with something like

```
Story                  Suffix
The Word Of Man         Man
The Man of Legend       Legend
The Boy of Egypt        Egypt
The Legend of Zelda     Zelda
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use `.str` twice, as `.str[-1]` will pick up the last element:

```
>>> df["Suffix"] = df["Story"].str.split().str[-1]
>>> df
                 Story Suffix
0              The Man    Man
1        The Man Child  Child
2     The Boy of Egypt  Egypt
3  The Legend of Zelda  Zelda
```

Comment: What if there is just one word in the string? We don't want that. How do we include that in the condition?

Answer (score 1):

To get the last word, you can make a list with each title being an entry in the list, and call this list comprehension to get all the suffixes:

```
suffixes = [item.split()[-1] for item in mylist]
```

This splits the strings by each word, and uses `[-1]` to get the last entry.

Then you can write it back whichever way you want.

The above list comprehension is equivalent to:

```
suffixes = []
for item in mylist:
    suffixes.append(item.split()[-1])) #item.split() to get a list of each word in the string, and [-1] to get the last word
```

Here is an example:

```
mylist = ['The Man', 'The Man Child', 'The Boy of Egypt', 'The Legend of Zelda']
suffixes = [item.split()[-1] for item in mylist]
print suffixes #['Man', 'Child', 'Egypt', 'Zelda']
```

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure I follow this logic -- could you provide any more detail?  Still learning my way around list comprehension.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think split is a little more clear than regex but you can `apply` any function you choose to a series.

```
final['Prefix'] = final['Story'].apply(lambda x: x.split()[-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there's any built in function to do it directly. You can iterate through the strings like

```
for i in xrange(len(df)):
    df['Suffix'].iat[i] = df['Story'].iat[i].split(' ')[len(df['Story'].iat[i].split(' '))-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use can use a regexp pattern to extract the last word:

```
In [10]:

df['suffix'] = df.Story.str.extract(r'((\b\w+)[\.?!\s]*$)')[0]
df
Out[10]:
                  Story  suffix
0               The Man     Man
1         The Man Child   Child
2      The Boy of Egypt   Egypt
3  The Legend of Zeldar  Zeldar
```

The pattern is a modified version of the answer I found here: [regex match first and last word or any word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20556934/regex-match-first-and-last-word-or-any-word)